# Add free gift after registering

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-group

We want to **offer a free gift to a specific customer group**. So, when someone registers under the specific customer group, the registration form submission will redirect to to the cart page and the free gift will be in the cart. I figured that we can set the price to zero for that customer group.

Can someone tell me how to redirect the registration submission to cart and how to add products to the cart automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a listener that redirects customers when they register.  This way, you can add some logic that will offer two different paths.  One will redirect customers to your current direction -- the other will direct customers to their cart where you will show them their free item.  You can add item to the cart at this stage too.